# Почему instance в синглтоне становится null?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс `UIManager`, написанный по принципу синглтона.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UIManager Instance;
    public List<GameObject> Windows = new List<GameObject>();
    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if (Instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        InitUI();
    }

    private void InitUI()
    {
        //to do
    }


    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var window in Windows)
        {
            var windowComponent = window.GetComponent<Window>();
            if (windowComponent is LoginWindow)
                windowComponent.Open();
            else
                windowComponent.Close();
        }
    }

    public T GetWindow<T>() where T : Window
    {
        foreach (var window in Windows)
        {
            var windowComponent = window.GetComponent<Window>();
            if (windowComponent is T)
                return (T)windowComponent;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Есть абстрактный класс `Window`, который реализуют все окна в сцене

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Window : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
    public Window CurrentWindow { get; protected set; } = null;

    public delegate void OpenEventHandler(Window sender);
    public event OpenEventHandler OnOpen;

    void Awake()
    {
        UIManager.Instance.Windows.Add(this.gameObject);
    }
    public void Open()
    {
        IsOpen = true;
        if (OnOpen != null)
            OnOpen(this);

        SelfOpen();
    }
    protected abstract void SelfOpen();
    public void Close()
    {
        IsOpen = false;

        if (CurrentWindow != null)
            CurrentWindow.Close();
        SelfClose();
    }
    protected abstract void SelfClose();

    protected void ChangeCurrentWindow(Window sender)
    {
        if (CurrentWindow != null)
            CurrentWindow.Close();
        CurrentWindow = sender;
    }
}
```

В `Window` в методе Awake() окно регистрируется в `UIManager`-е путем добавления ссылки на окно в список. Но возникает странное поведение, когда я запускаю сцену из редактора, то часть окон регистрируется, а часть нет, потому что `Instance` в менеджере становится равным `null`. Отсюда вопрос, почему он становится null? Если сбилдить проект, то там все работает нормально, но это не объясняет сути.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорей всего все дело в том что у вас какие-то скрипты выполняются раньше, какие то позже. Поставьте класс `UIManager` в настройках `Edit\ProjectSettings\ScriptExecutionOrders` в начало списка, тогда и в редакторе должно нормально все отрабатывать.

Answer (score 1):

Странный у вас синглтон. Почему экземпляр класса задается при вызове метода `Awake`?

Попробуйте использовать нормальный паттерн:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements the singleton design pattern.
/// A class inheriting from this class can be instantiated as a single instance.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Class type of the singleton instance.</typeparam>
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehavior where T : new()
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Static instance. Needs to use lambda expression
    /// to construct an instance (since constructor is private).
    /// </summary>
    private static Lazy<T> _instance = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance of this singleton.
    /// </summary>
    public static T Instance
    {
        get => _instance.Value;
        set
        {
            _instance = new Lazy<T>(() => value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

После этого:

```
public class UIManager : Singleton<UIManager>
{
    ... // Добавьте ваши методы здесь
}
```

Обращение к экземпляру осуществлять через

```
UIManager.Instance
```

Comment: Я воспользовался реализацией синглтона отсюда: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/level-generation?projectId=5c514a00edbc2a0020694718#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b6f7 И также в документации Unity говорится, что в классах наследниках `MonoBehaviour` не желательно определять конструктор, т.к. это может нарушить работу Unity.

Comment: А где вы увидели конструктор? =)

Comment: Я могу ошибиться в этой строчке `public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehavior where T : new()`, но насколько мне известно ограничение `:new()` укзывает, что тип должен иметь конструктор, сам я не определял конструктор, думаю он уже есть внутри `MonoBehaviour`, поэтому оно вообще скомпилировалось, но Unity посылает warning, гласящий, что я пытаюсь добавить компонент с помощью конструктора, тогда как лучше это делать через `AddComponent<>()`.

Comment: Ограничение `new()` говорит о том, что у `generic` типа, должен быть открытый конструктор без параметров, не более.

Comment: А, я разобрался `private static Lazy<T> _instance = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());`, я обращаюсь к инстансу, вызывается конструктор T, а T наследник  `MonoBehaviour`, вот unity и агрится